# Are there any map formats/standards and api's available to map local maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am trying to develop an app wherein I want to map a local map and then subsequently  provide direction guidelines to my users depending on the same. I want this as an android app and hence looking for formats which I could use to map or create local maps.

Is anyone aware of such frameworks or formats?

some I came across are KML,GPX and KMZ .. any one who has done work on these to create localised maps.

Answer (score 0):

You will get your answer in [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) for displaying maps.

To show directions , use this intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+source_latitude + ","+source_longitude+ "&daddr=" dest_latitude + ","dest_longitude));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi Charles ,the issue is I want to make localised maps specifically in formats such as KML ,or googles map format . Just needed to know some help on these